# Why is $5^n*(1-1/n)^n > 5^m *(1-1/n)^m $ for $m<n$ and $n>1?$

Tags: real-analysis, inequality

Let $n$ be a positive integer greater than $1.$ If $m<n,$ is a positive integer less than $n,$ it seems as if the following inequality is true:

$$5^n*(1-1/n)^n > 5^m*(1-1/n)^m.$$

How would I go about showing this is true, if it is? Can we get a more approximation of how much these two expressions differ? The obvious thing would be of course to divide both sides and prove that $$5^{n-m} (1-1/n)^{n-m} < 1.$$ But this seems just as hard as the previous inequality. One idea would be to maybe prove the inequality

$$5^n(1-1/n)^n > 5^m(1-1/n)$$ and then we must show that 
$$5^{n-m} (1-1/n)^{n-1} > 1.$$

Any solution would be welcome.

Comment: For $x>1$ and $n,m\in\Bbb Z_{>0}$, we have $$n>m\implies x^n>x^m$$

Comment: Welcome to MSE. Please use $\times$ instead of $*$.

Comment: @Dave Yes, but $(1-1/n)^n$ and $(1-1/n)^m$ are both less than $1.$

Comment: @Inequalitynoob but $5-\frac{5}{n}>1$.

Comment: Yes, but the power of $5$ brings the terms above $1$.

Comment: I realized I mistyped the above question. Can I delete it, or should I let it be?

Comment: @Inequalitynoob You can edit it. What's the mistake?

Comment: Let me guess: should it be $\;m\;$ on the right hand fraction?

Comment: @DonAntonio It is more complex, I will write it up in a minute.

Answer (score 1):

You have to prove, according to what you wrote, that

$$n>m\implies5^n\left(1-\frac1n\right)^n>5^m\left(1-\frac1n\right)^m\iff5^{n-m}\left(1-\frac1n\right)^{n-m}>1\iff$$

$$\left(5-\frac5n\right)^{n-m}>1\iff 5-\frac5n>1$$

and since the last inequality is trivialy true for $\;n\ge2\;$, we're done.

Comment: I agree. Can we say anything more about how big the difference is?

Answer (score 0):

The idea, as Dave writes is that when $x > 1$ then $x^n > x^m$ when $n > m$. In this case

$$ x = 5(1 - 1/n) = 5 - 5/n. $$

This is $>1$ when

\begin{align}
5 - 5/n &> 1 \\
5n - 5 &> n \\
4n - 5 &> 0 \\
4n &> 5 \\
n &> 5/4.
\end{align}

Well, in this case we know this is true because $n \ge 2$.

---

The difference, since you've asked is

$$ (5 - 5/n)^n - (5 - 5/n)^m = (5 - 5/n)^m ((5 - 5/n)^{n - m} - 1). $$

Now it depends on what $m$ and $n$ are. Let's say $m$ is roughly linear in $n$. Say $m = \alpha n - k$ where $0 \le \alpha  \le 1$.

If $\alpha < 1$ then $(5 - 5/n)^{n - m} \gg 1$ and the difference is approximately

$$ (5 - 5/n)^n \approx 5^n e^{-1}. $$

If $\alpha = 1$, the difference is approximately

$$ 5^n (1 - 5^{-k}) e^{-1}. $$

For instance when $\alpha = 1$ and $k = 1$ the difference is approximately

$$ \frac45 5^n e^{-1}. $$