# An inequality involving powers of $5$ and $n.$

Tags: real-analysis, inequality

This is related to [a question I previously asked](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2576078/why-is-5n1-1-nn-5m-1-1-nm-for-mn-and-n1), but I thought it was better to write a new question since this is somewhat different.

Let $m$ and $n$ be positive integers with $m<n$. Prove that:
$$5^n \left( 1 - \frac 1 {2^n} \right)^{2^n} > 5^m \left( 1 - \frac 1 {2^n} \right)^{2^m}$$

I suppose that what we want to show is similar to the previous question, namely that:

$5^{m/2^m} -5^{m/2^m}/2^n$ is greater than $1$ for $m \leq n.$ This should be true, but I do not see an obvious way to show it.

Comment: clarification - if the left hand side has 3 '$n$'s, should the right hand side have 2 '$m$'s and one '$n$'?

Comment: @CalvinKhor That is correct.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The wanted inequality can be rephrased using $k:=n-m>0$
$$ 5^{k} \left(1 - \frac{1}{2^n}\right)^{2^n(1-2^{-k})} \overset{?}{>} 1$$
Note that the exponent of the bracketed term $2^n(1-2^{-k}) ≥ 1$. Hence by [Bernoulli's inequality](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bernoulli%27s_inequality),
$$5^k\left(1 - \frac{1}{2^n}\right)^{2^n(1-2^{-k})} ≥ 5^k(1-(1-2^{-k}))=(5/2)^k$$
which is bigger than 1.

Comment: Beautiful, thank you!

Comment: @Inequalitynoob note there was a mistake, but the result remains true.

Comment: @CalvinKhor I've the following doubt on the application of Bernoulli inequality: $$\left(1 - \frac{1}{2^n}\right)^{2^n(1-2^{-k})}\geq \left(1 - \frac{(1-2^{-k})}{2^n}\right)^{2^n}$$

Are you sure you can assume $r=2^n(1-2^{-k})$?

Comment: @gimusi are you worried its not an integer? Bernoulli holds for all $r≥1$.

Comment: @CalvinKhor it is because in this case you have the term $2^n$ both inside and at the exponent

Comment: @gimusi Where in Bernoulli does it say "unless you have $2^n$ both here and there"?

Comment: @CalvinKhor You are right. Thanks!

Comment: @gimusi glad to help